Why git push for amended commit re-upload already uploaded files?
I'm using github repo as file hosting, I don't want to keep the history. So there's only single commit, that amended every time and pushed with force.
The problem - it's very slow, seems like it's re-uploading files that's already uploaded.
The command
git add -A
git commit --amend -m 'upd'
git push -f origin main

The git output
 248 files changed, 992 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 .gitignore
 ... lots of other files ...
 create mode 100644 some-file
Enumerating objects: 280, done.
Counting objects: 100% (280/280), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (277/277), done.
Writing objects: 100% (280/280), 50.69 MiB | 664.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 280 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
To github.com:some-user/some-project.git
 + 23aa088...a315819 main -> main (forced update)

How to fix it, or maybe there are better ways (git commands) to use github repo as a file hosting?

BTW: This also means that when fetching from a third repo, you always transmit the full payload, too, and that any info already present locally is ignored as well.
